# Where to get the Alchemyapi API key?

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

I'm doing the, `Getting Started with AlchemyAPI Using Ruby`, Ruby tutorial. But I cannot seem to find my API key.

Source: http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/getting-started-guide/using-alchemyapi-with-ruby

**At step 3:**

> 3) Configure the Ruby SDK to use your API Key Now that you have the
>   Ruby SDK code on your computer, you need to do configure it to use
>   your API key. In the alchemyapi_ruby directory, run:

```
ruby alchemyapi.rb YOUR_API_KEY
```

> Where YOUR_API_KEY is the 40 character API key you received in your
>   e-mail when you registered. If everything goes okay, you should see
>   the following output:

But I didn't get an API Key in an email...

The tutorial sent me to IBM Bluemix to register, which I have.

This is the email from signing up.

> Hi XXX,
>
> Thank you for signing up for Bluemix! During your trial, you'll have
>   access to Bluemix to build apps, with 2 GB of runtime and container
>   memory, as well as up to 10 provisioned Bluemix services. And, you
>   won't need to provide any form of payment for this trial.
>
> Confirm your account to start your 30-day trial.
>
> If you have any problems logging in, let us know at IBM Bluemix
>   Support.
>
> Welcome to Bluemix!
>
> --IBM Bluemix Team

After confirming - still no API Key. I've logged into the Bluemix site and have been searching around but also don't see it.

I apologize in advance if I've missed something obvious. But I'm wasting a lot of time here and would really appreciate any help :)

Has anyone signed up for this service recently and been able to get their API key. Can you tell me where it came from?

Comment: Figured it out. Incase anyone else gets stuck. Login to Bluemix > Watson > Alchemyapi > Create > Service Credentials. And you'll find it :)

Answer (score 6):

Login to Bluemix, go to `Services & APIs`. In `Watson` section chose `AlchemyAPI` and create one. After `AlchemyAPI` is created go to the dashboard and select created instance.

Under `Service Credentials` you can find the apikey:

[image]

Comment: I have done this, but my key is still showing up as invalid. I have waited > 5 mins (>10 hours).

Comment: Remove this service and create another one. If this doesn't help contact the support.

Comment: I don't have this page what so ever on my bluemix. all I have is username and password.

Answer (score 0):

After the acquisition of AlchemyApi by IBM the endpoints have changed hence the old legacy code in GitHub will not be able to use the key which you get from ibm bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the watson --> then on the previously created credentials --> again click create. Then highlight the 'service credentials' to see the json format details.