# How to find an alchemy API key?

Tags: node.js, sentiment-analysis, watson

I was wondering where can I find my alchemy API key on Bluemix? I looked at the following question on SO ([Where to get the Alchemyapi API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438315/where-to-get-the-alchemyapi-api-key)) however, my bluemix looks nothing like that.

I do not have an apikey field, only username and password along with a url. IBM's documentations are approaching the usefulness of Java Docs (I.E, loads of info very little as far as demos go)

Below is how my creds look like:

```
{
  "url": "so_url",
  "username": "3e49e046-....",
  "password": "XXXX"
}
```

I downloaded the npm module using the following instructions (https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud#alchemylanguage) it mentions that username and password are the api key, so do they just get concatenated together? Is there anything that I missing from my Bluemix by chance?

The way i have my api key now, i.e where it is just username and password merged together returns an invalid api key error.

Comment: You should switch to NLU which will be replacing Alchemy.

Comment: yeah, found it in the end, IBM has their documentation spread all over their websites.